# Mouse wheel button not shown in CP, and non-standard behaviour if Firefox

Tags: release-freya, mouse

Hi there Freya does not work but using Linux Mint my mouse wheel is available in the CP. When using FF I press and hold, and expect it to scroll page up/down according to mouse movement when held down.

How can I get the wheel option to show under Elementary CP/mouse settings??

Thanks kindly.
Alistair.